# how can i refer to the children of generic type

Tags: typescript

I would like to have a general type checking on the keys of provided object and its children. here is the idea:

```
type A<T> = {
  key: keyof T;
  childKey: keyof T[this.key] // i dont know how to make this work
};
```

if the above type works:

```
const a = {  child1: { param: 1 }, child2: { param: 1 } };


const myObj: A<typeof a> = {
  key: "child3",        // << child3 is not a key of a
  childKey: "param"
}

const myObj: A<typeof a> = {
  key: "child1",        
  childKey: "param2"    // << param2 is not a key of a.child1
}
```

i tried `keyof T[this.key]`, `keyof T["key"]`, `keyof ThisType["key]`, none of them are giving me correct behvaiour. Can someone gives me suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you probably want to create a union of all valid `key` and `childKey` combinations. This can be done by mapping over the keys and nested keys.

```
type A<T> = {
   [K1 in keyof T]: {
      [K2 in keyof T[K1]]: {
         key: K1,
         childKey: K2
      }
   }[keyof T[K1]]
}[keyof T]

const myObj: A<typeof a> = {
  key: "child3",        // Type '"child3"' is not assignable to type '"child1" | "child2"'
  childKey: "param"
}

const myObj2: A<typeof a> = {
  key: "child1",        
  childKey: "param2"    // Type '"param2"' is not assignable to type '"param"'
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4&ssl=21&ssc=2&pln=13&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3jGwAWBLANgEwEYAuVGABzgCc4BbUwmAXwBoMcCAmUtSm%20mIybMA3ACgJUAJ7kApjACCAHgAqAPiSox6GAG0A0o2xgYAa1lSQAMxgqAuj2070BzjGNmL12wcJ2HWs5B5lKkhixOQehYePj6FmGckTpMkUy6Id4qvv5i6Zk29hKgkLC0UgDyAEYAVqTK0nLecBrIKE4hpABEMQQAzF1sUTAA9CO2MvIA5D0c%20ANT7hAwYCCwcBAQ2ADmYHBVuPJQIDCN07OxhF0wAD4wF1xdU069cQn3fHRdecXg0DDlao1biKJRnZqtQKeUL3V5XIZRF5zeIwrqfWica46MYTOQwGbozGLbDLVbrTY7PYHI4nM74tHUL7PJhAA)